# ggplot alter map fill opacity by second variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I'm creating a cloropleth map of the U.S where each county is colored by the proportion of the 2012 votes for Obama.  I'd like to vary the opacity of county overlays by the population (similar to what was done [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151321923986667&set=a.53699096666.80512.605431666&type=1&theater)).  I've tried adding alpha = populationVariable to my geom_map aes, but without luck.

Here is my current code. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=mapC, map=mapC, aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id, group=group, fill=mapC$proportionObama))
gg = gg+ scale_fill_gradient2(limits= c(0,100), name="Proportion of Votes for Obama", low="#E5000A", high="#0012BF",mid="#720964", midpoint=50)
gg = gg + theme_map() +coord_equal()
gg <- gg + geom_path(data = mapS,  aes(long,lat, group=group), colour="gray50", size=.25)
gg = gg + theme(legend.position="right")
gg
```

Comment: Don't use `$` inside `aes()`. You mostly do this, but your fill mapping should be `fill = proportionObama`. It will work in some simple cases, but will cause bugs in more complicated plots.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example...

Comment: (1) SO provides a way to embed images. (2) Please use `coord_map('polyconic')` to show conUS images or at the very least use `coord_map()` vs ` coord_equal()`. (3) Alaska, Hawaii & Puerto Rico all voted, too and you're excluding them. (4) Why not just use a bar chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `alpha` needs to be a variable that's mapped to be between 0 and 1. The `ggplot` documentation always shows a fractional value.

- [Hue Scale - http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_hue.html](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_hue.html)
- [Color Fill Alpha - http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/aes_colour_fill_alpha.html](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/aes_colour_fill_alpha.html)

You don't have reproducible code, so here was a quick test that seemed to work.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)


tmp = data.table(
  'x'=c(1,2,3),
  'y'=c(1,2,3),
  'z'=c(.1,.5,.8)
)

p = ggplot()
p = p + geom_point( data=tmp , aes(x=x,y=y,alpha=z))
print(p)
```

Comment: ggplot will map rescale any atomic column to the range for alpha. I'm not sure what this has to do with the question.

Comment: I believe my issue was that I was using an alpha that was so small (proportion of us population in each county) that it was just mapping everything as (virtually) completely transparent.

Comment: @Martin: hrbrmstr is correct - if **all** your alpha values had been small, it wouldn't have mattered. Your problem is that the *range* of values is very big, but almost all the values are at the lower end of the distribution. With LA county having ~10M people, any county with less than 1M people (~2990 of the 3007 counties) will be virtually invisible. A better way to do it might be to use logarithmic bins, something like 0-10k, 10k-100k, 100k-1M, 1M-10M.